# Deploy angular2 universal on a windows server

Tags: node.js, angular, .net-core, angular-universal

I'm evaluating Angular2 Universal for a new project. I've played around with [universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) and also with [aspnetcore-angular2-universal](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal) for using with asp.net core (which for now, decided not to use core, since manipulating the title and head tags on the **server side** is not available at the moment). However, as fascinating as angular universal can be, I cant seem to find a complete guide on how to deploy and run a production angular universal website on a windows server. I have a server that will host my .net web-api, and I want to host the angular there too. (I must mention that I'm new to angular2 and this is my first project with that framework).

How and what do I need to configure on the server? (Do I need to install node\npm?) and what do I need to take from build and where do I put it? (I have two folders at my `dist` foldaer - `client` and `server` - where do they go?)